# Wordpress google custom search integration not showing results

Tags: php, wordpress, google-custom-search

I want to integrate Google custom search to my wordpress site.

I have added my site into Google Custom Search and I generated the script and put into my wordpress page. I typed a keyword in my custom search box and pressed search button, its showing no results.

How can fix this problem.

this is my code :

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '005684269769708879665:sggzaz_druu';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: Could you post some source code for your Google Custom search function? It would help us to debug the issue you are having.

Comment: @buzzlightyear I edited my question , added code , check it